# Speller in gedit won't change words

Tags: gedit, spell-checking

I'm using gedit and the speller actually highlight the misspelled words. But when I right-click the word and choose the correct word it won't change. Also I can't choose to add a new word.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the permissions on your options file has been incorrectly set. Can you navigate to the file /home/<USERNAME>*/.config/gedit *(Go to the hidden folder `.config` and right click on the gedit folder, then select properties from the drop down menu)* and make sure that the permissions are set to the following: ****(swap your username for <USERNAME>)***

[image]

If they do not look like this, let me know and we'll sort it out.

Comment: I can't open that.

Comment: I have added some instructions on my answer. If you still can not do it, let me know.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: What's not working? Can you find the file? What goes wrong? Is it when you right click on it?

Comment: I found it but it's already as yours.

Comment: I am facing this problem too, and still no luck. Sometimes, it works, I change to suggestion, but only in limited time. It also applies for "change case".

Answer (score 0):

I just found a method to make it works again.
Just try to cut a word (Ctrl+C), and type something (or paste what you cut).
Now when I am trying to change case or correct to spelling suggestion (right click), it works.
It may related to a bug or a plugin that I installed previously (vim-mode??)